# Grails GORM issue regarding missing method

Tags: grails, grails-orm

**UPDATE: I've altered the contents of the initial post. I've attempted to simplify my original question, and I have also provided some additional information**

I've been attempting to use db-reverse-engineer on a legacy MS SQL Server database. Prior to my attempts with an actual system, I went through the db-reverse-engineer tutorial to familiarize myself with the tool and the patterns I might need for my production-based database.

After running db-reverse-engineer on our project, I copied out the entity code to a Groovy script that uses *GORM standalone* (reference this Gist for the complete code: https://gist.github.com/restagner/f2f740d5599efa202b08).

When I attempt to run the script, it produces the following error and creates a brand new table labeled `master_licenses`. I'm at a loss as to how to fix this.

I was under the impression that I could use the addTo* style methods to add certain domain objects.  I'm sure that  I'm overlooking something obvious here, but I just can't quite figure it out.  I have reviewed the Grails documentation, but could not pick up on where I'm going wrong.

```
Mar 13, 2015 8:19:16 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table master_licenses add constraint     FK_fh56msfgiqs28dhbqp4uyt34f foreign key (master_id) references master
Mar 13, 2015 8:19:16 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: Column 'master.master_id' is not the same data type as referencing column 'master_licenses.master_id' in foreign key 'FK_fh56msfgiqs28dhbqp4uyt34f'.

Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:    Master.addToLicenses() is applicable for argument types: (License) values:     [License : (unsaved)]
Possible solutions: getLicenses()
```

And, here is a list of the DDLs for each table represented

```
CREATE TABLE license (
    license_id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    artist_id int,
    territory_id int,
    project varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    project_type_id int,
    label_id char(3),
    fee money DEFAULT ((0.00)),
    fee_currency_id int,
    licensee_id int,
    contract_date datetime,
    license_status_id char(1),
    license_term_id char(1),
    term_end_date datetime,
    notes nvarchar(max),
    setup_by_id varchar(10),
    setup_date datetime,
    updated_by_id varchar(10),
    updated_date datetime,
    term_notes varchar(4000),
    fee_id int,
    royalty_term varchar(50),
    license_status_notes varchar(4000),
    media_type_id int,
    media_type_notes varchar(255),
    option_ind char(1),
    option_notes varchar(4000),
    territory_notes varchar(255),
    license_product_id int,
    release_date datetime,
    return_date datetime,
    licensee_contact nvarchar(255),
    amount_received money,
    balance_of_advance money,
    royalties_earned money,
    units int,
    PRIMARY KEY (license_id)
);
```

Master table

```
CREATE TABLE master (
    master_id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    title nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
    original_label_id char(3) NOT NULL,
    duration nvarchar(8),
    recording_type_id int NOT NULL,
    asset_type nvarchar(5),
    isrc nvarchar(15),
    sap_issue_num char(12),
    language_id smallint,
    p_notice_year nvarchar(4),
    p_notice_text nvarchar(255),
    recording_date_text nvarchar(100),
    territory_id int,
    location_recording nvarchar(255),
    location_mixing nvarchar(255),
    location_mastering nvarchar(255),
    aftra_ind char(1),
    afm_ind char(1),
    courtesy_of_text nvarchar(255),
    comments nvarchar(max),
    parental_advisory_ind char(1),
    status char(1),
    royalty_master_id numeric(18),
    country_of_origin_id int,
    contain_samples char(1),
    misc_label_copy nvarchar(max),
    asset_type_id int,
    setup_by_id nvarchar(10),
    setup_date datetime NOT NULL,
    updated_by_id nvarchar(10),
    updated_date datetime,
    english_title nvarchar(255),
    version_title nvarchar(80),
    parental_ind_id int,
    isrc_cloned nvarchar(15),
    send_to_umg_ind char(1),
    send_to_umg_date datetime,
    PRIMARY KEY (master_id)
);
```

License_Master table -- the join table

```
CREATE TABLE license_master (
    license_id int NOT NULL,
    master_id int,
    setup_by_id char(10),
    setup_date datetime,
    updated_by_id char(10),
    updated_date datetime,
    amount money
);
```

Comment: Might saving the license before using addToLicenses fix the issue?

Comment: I've not seen the use of `@Entity` annotations before - is there a reason why you don't put the domain classes in the `grails-app/domain` directory? Where does this script exist? Perhaps Grails does some magic on the classes if they are in the domain directory, rather than elsewhere?

Comment: My apologies, but I'm taking the domain classes and trying to run them with GORM standalone, outside of grails. I've had success with this approach, but just reading from tables.  This is my first attempt at trying to use this approach with a many-to-many relationship.